# How do I change the ParameterTree font size?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm working on a PyQt4 GUI. My issue is that it looks very different when I run the code from windows or linux. I think the main reason is the difference in default font size between platforms. With that in mind, I wanted to change the font size of the pyqtgraph's ParameterTree. How can I do that?

If you have a more general answer that could help solving all the differences, it would be greatly appreciated.